# Scully.io Prerenders only ROOT route as static file but does not prerender ANY other routes

Tags: angular, prerender, scully, scullyio, angular-scully

We have set up of entire **Angular 14.2.12** application in Production working just fine.  I wanted to generate some of static pages using Scully, so I added Scully by following steps

> ng add @scullyio/init

This installed scully in my project

> Then, I ran "ng build" and "npx scully",

So, **Scully recognized only the ROOT route (LandingPageComponent) and scully created index.html file for the root.**
...But as per my below routing file, **my app has many other routes**, ***but scully is not recoginzing those other routes and is not generating any other static files***.

Can you please reivew the below configuration and let me know what am I missing or where is my mistake?

---

Here is my src/app/app-routing.module.ts

> ```
> @NgModule({
>         imports: [
>                 RouterModule.forRoot([
>                         { 
>                                 path: 'price', component: PriceComponent
>                         },
>                         {
>                                 path: 'privacy-policy', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent
>                         },
>                         {
>                                 path: 'legal-questions', component: LegalQuestionsComponent
>                         },
>                         {
>                                 path: 'training', component: TrainingComponent
>                         },  
>                         { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent },
>                         { path: '**', component: LandingPageComponent },
>                         { path: '', redirectTo: './app.component', pathMatch: 'full' },
>                 ], {
>     enableTracing: false,
>     onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
>     scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
>     anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
>     relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy'
> })     
>         ],
>         exports: [
>                 RouterModule
>         ],
>         declarations: []
> })
> export class AppRoutingModule { }
> ```

---

Here is scully config file

> ```
> test/scully.test.config.ts
>
> import { ScullyConfig } from '@scullyio/scully';
>
> import '@scullyio/scully-plugin-puppeteer'
>
> export const config: ScullyConfig = {
>   projectRoot: "./src",
>   projectName: "test",
>   distFolder: './dist/test',
>   outDir: './dist/static',
>   routes: {
>   }
> };
> ```

---

Thank you in advance for your help.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the path to render specific route with extraRoutes in `scully.projectname.config.ts`

```
import { ScullyConfig } from '@scullyio/scully';

export const config: ScullyConfig = {
  projectRoot: './src',
  projectName: 'projectname',
  outDir: './dist/static',
  routes: {},
  extraRoutes: ['/price', '/privacy-policy', ... ] // add extra routes here
};
```

Hope this helps!